# Recursively generating random objects in Java

Tags: java, random, dynamically-generated, solver

What library / method can I use for deep generation of random objects for a given class in Java / Scala?
By deep generation I mean recursively filling the entire object graph with random values, for both primitive and complex types.

The goal is to use randomly generated mock objects for tests.

To make the tests consistent and reproducible, the set of generated objects should be identical on every run.

Comment: Why are you planning to do this? It seems an unusual request and perhaps if we understand the context, we can recommend an alternative approach.

Comment: In most cases you have to define which objects are valid and which are not. I doubt that there is a library to perform such generation on an arbitrary class -- it's hard to imagine why that would be useful. Generation of random vectors in high-dimensional spaces or random strings, trees or graphs makes much more sense and there're libraries for that.

Comment: @DuncanJones, I need it to automatically create a wide variety of randomly generated mock objects for tests.

Comment: @Qnan, this task is technically feasible using reflection, but requires some work to get it right. I wonder if anyone has already done this before.

Comment: There's a pretty good argument that tests should be deterministic. You don't want tests that have previously passed to start failing unless you've actually introduced a bug. Also, being able to write the right tests for the code creates parts of the benefit of testing as it encourages you understand and structure the code better.

Comment: @SagieDavidovich It's only feasible if you have no constraints on the field values whatsoever or can specify those constraints in a form readable to the generation algorithm. Plus there is a question of the distribution you draw each random sample from.
If the objects are interconnected that's not going to be trivial.

Comment: Having said that, I'm also interested in understanding your use case more as if it is a valid approach it's pretty interesting.

Comment: @Russell that's not the point, it's quite easy to specify the set of "random" object by setting the seed and/or some numerical parameters. Or even serializing and reusing them.

Comment: @SagieDavidovich so long as you have only integer/float/string values in there it shouldn't be much of a problem, I think.

Comment: @Qnan Yes, but I don't think that is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Russell as you've pointed out yourself, there's not much sense in generation non-reproducible test cases. Or do you mean the assumptions about the fields?..

Comment: @Qnan I think we're arguing from the same position completely. There's not much sense in generating non-reproducible test cases, however, I get the impression this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Russell, I agree that tests should be deterministic and reproducible.
Let's assume that the random objects are generated using the same seed, which makes the generator produce a consistent, but very large and distinct set of different objects. I'm going to edit the original question to clarify that tests should be reproducible if the same random seed is used.

Comment: @SagieDavidovich glad to hear it! So I'm interested in the nature of your use case. Have you got an absolutely gigantic object graph? Why would you not need to create the test objects yourself, so that you can be sure you're covering boundary conditions etc? If there's a lot of nested objects rather than just primitive fields, why aren't you testing each object individually and mocking out its dependencies?

Comment: @Russell, the goal is to simplify test case generation and finding failing cases faster. The object graph may be small, but the tests will only fail in some cases.
For reference, Pex automatically generates test suites for .Net with high code coverage, using the Z3 solver ( http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/ )

There are similar solutions in Java. In my case, I need just the part that generates the objects, not the complete test generation package.

Comment: I guess I just don't agree with that idea. For me, a large part of the benefit of tests is that you write them before, or at least while you are writing the actual code, helping you write better code. Good luck though, I hope you find your solution! :-)

Comment: @Russell, thanks for the feedback anyway :)
This idea is not new, Jtest is a very popular framework which is based on this paradigm (http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/jtest.jsp?itemId=14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there are there are two powerful methods to randomly generate very large, arbitrary types of object. The first is called the **recursive method** (introduced by Wilf and Nijenhuis, [formalized](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/RR-1830.pdf) by Flajolet, van Cutsem and Zimmerman), the second is called **[Boltzmann sampling](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/DuFlLoSc02.pdf)** by Duchon, Flajolet, Louchard and Schaeffer.

In both methods, you give a structure definition (a "grammar") and you are returned with a large random object which is in accordance with the grammar.

Both have been used very successfully in wide scale testing of programs (similar to Haskell's [QuickCheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck)). Unfortunately, while there are some various implementations of the methods, I don't think there is a ready to use library for Java. For example of what can be done, you might want to check [Yann Ponty's page](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~ponty/index.php?lang=en&page=software&css=bioinfo) with Java implementations of these methods for bioinformatics. If you were using OCaml, then Alexis Darrasse and Benjamin Canou have implemented [a useful subset of Boltzmann sampling](http://genal.algo-prog.info/?p=genadt) as a completely autonomous library for algebraic types (sumtypes).

Comment: @SagieDavidovich: you're welcome! I just remembered Darrasse also worked on adapting Boltzmann sampling to randomly generate big XML documents given the grammar, see [here](http://www.labri.fr/perso/xblanc/data/papers/ECMDA09.pdf). In any case, if you have a more specific usage case, maybe I can give you additional details (I've used both generation methods before myself).

Answer (score 1):

The [InPUT](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT) library can help you doing this in Java. You specify the structures in XML in a so called design space which defines the valid ranges. In the code then you simply call

```
IDesignSpace ds = new DesignSpace("designSpace.xml");
TheType o = ds.next("TheTypeId");
```

The object o is now randomly instantiated according to what you accept as valid value ranges in the XML. [Here](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT/wiki/Tutorials) you find tutorials and examples. Reproducibility is addressed in [this tutorial](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT/wiki/Random-Value).

Answer (score 0):

Some research showed me that there is a great framework for Scala called [ScalaCheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/), which was inspired by QuickCheck, which [Jérémie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408734/jeremie) mentioned above.
Though it's build for Scala, it can be used in Java as well (though without the syntactic sugar)